# C# LINQ Zip: find at least one pair

Tags: c#, linq

I have two arrays and I'd like to know if some condition satisfy **at least one pair** from the lists.

Minimum reproducing code:

```
    var boxTypes = new string[] { "Banana", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana" };
    var boxSizes = new int[] { 31, 16, 35, 8 };

    int bigBoxSize = 20;
    bool hasBigAppleBox = 
        boxTypes.Zip(boxSizes,
                     (type, size) => (type == "Apple" && size >= bigBoxSize) ? 1 : 0)
                .Sum() > 0;
```

This code iterates through all pairs. But one pair is enough.

Any suggestion to improve this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Use `Any(result => result > 1)`

Long answer: Your use of `Sum()` is going to evaluate the entire collection, and using `Any()` will only evaluate until the first `true` condition is met.

Example:

```
boxTypes.Zip(boxSizes,
            (type, size) => (type == "Apple" && size >= bigBoxSize) ? 1 : 0)
            .Any(result => result == 1)
```

It's also worth noting that your `(type == "Apple" && size >= bigBoxSize) ? 1 : 0` predicate can be simplified in this case to just be `type == "Apple" && size >= bigBoxSize)`.

With this, your statement becomes:

```
boxTypes.Zip(boxSizes,
            (type, size) => type == "Apple" && size >= bigBoxSize)
            .Any()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
bool hasBigAppleBox = 
    boxTypes.Zip(boxSizes,
                 (type, size) => type == "Apple" && size >= bigBoxSize)
            .Any(x => x);
```

Basically, for each pair, this code selects the result of the condition for that pair. This (the `Zip` method) returns an `IEnumerable<bool>`. `Any(x => x)` would return true when it meets the first `true` in the enumerable.